# Rich GUI application in Delphi

Tags: delphi, user-interface

I would like to create an application with rich UI elements and no VCL in Delphi (except a TForm). Each components (buttons, list, etc...) needs to support full per pixel alpha and be easily created without any codes. It should be skinnable and able to give result similar to adobe air application.

I've tried with GR32 (Graphics32), but each instance of TImage32 take too much memory.

Do you know any frameworks or components for Delphi 2009 that would allow me create a set of components for making rich UI application ?

Cheers!

**EDIT : 
The current alpha version of my application look like this :
[image]**

I would like to have similar result but without using a TImage32 for each components (buttons, labels, panels, etc...)

Comment: Why are so strict to NOT use VCL?

Comment: For making less "MS Windows" style software. I'm making an IM client and I would it to have custom appearance (like Trilian Astra)

Comment: You might want to reconsider that design decision.  Inconsistent user interfaces tend to make your product harder to use.  See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000061.html for the rationale.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler : The idea is to make the IM Client appearance customizable for improving the user experience. That's why, I would like to use the same kind of working mechanism as in Windows but with completely different appearance.

@ smok1 : VCL components will look strange if used in a completely different GUI style. Moreover, VCL components appearance is not very predictable depending of the version of Windows (mostly, Win2K, WinXP and Vista/Windows 7)

Comment: IM client, custom skin? Sort of like Skype? Hmm, Skype is written in Delphi, and I'll bet it contains VCL components. Go with the DevExpress skin controller, and you'll find it works very well.

Comment: Yes, but more like Trillian Astra (http://www.trillian.im/learn/tour-contactlist.html). Skype appearance is very similar to windows and there is not advanced customization (doesn't seem to support per-pixel alpha) which are available.

Comment: @Ariel R - See my answer below

Answer (score 6):

[alt text http://www.ksdev.com/vgscene/snapshot/screen1.jpeg](http://www.ksdev.com/vgscene/snapshot/screen1.jpeg)

Have you looked at [VGScene](http://www.ksdev.com/vgscene/snapshot/screen1.jpeg), it's looks like more as Adobe Flash or Microsoft WPF.

Comment: Hi ! I've already checked VGScene - it seems to be the closest framework for making what I would like. But unfortunately, VGScene seems quite new and not very well documented and the way it works is quite different from the VCL. I will check the latest release, thanks !

Comment: VGScene has now been discontinued.

Comment: @Shannonen iiuc VGScene morphed to FireMonkey in XE2

Comment: vgscene morphed to firemonkey and now I will need to revert back to VCL again.. i would concidered to use firemonkey if it was just possible to merge it with a few native VCL's like quantum grid.. but that wont work, so now my nice rich gui will need to go back to plain vcl again :)

Answer (score 4):

It's strange. You want to use Delphi but you won't use VCL?

Can you use Skinned controls? There are good skin packages. For Skin packages you can [see here](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=1544) and download some demos.
You can also try the ["Smooth Controls" from TMS](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advsmoothcontrols.asp).

[image]

Regards.

Comment: I've tried most skin packages that are shown on Torrys, but none of them support advanced drawing on form. It's for example impossible to create an UI like MacOS X (with smooth border, shadow arround the form, etc...).

Answer (score 3):

I would advise to have a go at using a TWebBrowser component on a form (with Align=alClient), and doing most UI using HTML/CSS. There are a number of tricks to load content into the TWebBrowser, such as using "res://" URL's loading resources that have been included in the excutable.

By adding the MSHTML unit to the uses clause, you can use IHTMLDocument2 and related interfaces on the WebBrowser1.Document property to manipulate the DOM, much like Web2.0 websites do these days.

Comment: If you like this approach and would have no problem running your application from within an Internet Explorer instance, have a look at this project I started, which implements IInternetProtocol: http://xxm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Right, but it's not the same as manipulating each components directly in the application (events on the components for example). Moreover, it becomes dependent of IE and doesn't allow any eye candy.

Comment: Using a WebBrowser component will work just fine for what you want to do. You will end up with effectively two apps, an HTML+Javascript+CSS UI and then a back end Delphi App. MVC style design recommended!

Comment: Well, yes, perhaps now I can get it what it is that the MVC-hype is about. Could you tell me more about what it takes to do 'MVC style design' in this case? Don't answer here, I've posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278725/what-does-an-mvc-delphi-with-webbroser-and-html-application-look-like

Answer (score 2):

Look at [ExpressSkins™ Library](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExSkins/info.xml) from DevExpress. The even have a built in [Mc skin](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExSkins/i/skins/skin_McSkin.png).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so as far as I see your ONLY option is actually to use VCL, but not plain VCL, as it comes with Delphi, but use some components library. The library you need must be highly customizable and have support for skins. I think the solution for you is [Developer Express](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/). Those components suit your needs:

1. Fully customizable, with a lot of support for skins and they look very different from classic windows GUI.
2. DevExpress usually cares about consistency between user environments – for example their web controls look the same in IE, Firefox and Opera. The same rule will apply to windows controls – they will look the same in various versions of Windows. At least – you will have control over appearance of your forms in different versions (in plain VCL you do not have control).
3. Excellent support and frequent updates make you comfortable – they are fixing bugs quite fast and feature requests are taken into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've already checked DevExpress components, but unfortunately like most skin components - it relies on Windows XP themes. It's quite old and doesn't support much features (no per-pixel alpha, no effects, no transition, etc...). Using DevExpress is like using enhanced componets and changing your theme on Windows with a utility like Windows Blind. It's not possible to create GUI like MacOS X or KDE.

Comment: @Ariel R: ok, so keep trying, hope you will find something useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should just draw the form yourself from onpaint ? (and handle all mouse, keyboard and focus issues)

Just make you own mini-framework. Delphi is object oriented so it's a good tool for the job.
I'm sure you can make it blitzing fast with a bit of help of GR32.

Comment: Yes, I've started doing this with GR32 - but it's much more works and harder to design a form.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Delphi's .NET interface. The .NET GUI is considered less windowy and might give you what you want fairly easily.

Here's [an example of what a .NET GUI application](http://www.chemaxon.com/marvin/examples/ChemAxon.NET/GUI/doc/index.html) can look like.

Delphi does have its own VCL for .NET, which can use .NET controls instead of Windows controls.

Alternatively, you can try [the JEDI VCL for Delphi at Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/). It's free, has over 600 components, and many can give you some different non-windows looks.

Comment: .NET is based on GDI/GDI+ native widgets afaik, and is not owner drawn.

Comment: Actually lkessler example points to a WPF example, and that is not nativ controls. WPF is a VERY GOOD match for the requirements in this question if you skip the "Delphi 2009" part.

Answer (score 0):

If you have time, wait for Delphi 2010, it will have Touch and Direct2D support where you can create complex GUI interfaces with a high end quality.

Also you can try to contact with the people of CrossGL http://www.crossgl.com/cgl_about.htm

They have a powerfull delphi vector based framework, they were selling it (for a high price) for some time. But I think they are making more money selling applications based on their framework.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an available frameworks. I'll try to take a look at it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SpTBXLib? I know of a couple skin editors that you can create your own skins for SpTBXLib. You can download a precompiled demo here:

http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/downloads.htm

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are not expecting people to use such an application. As they wont. There are no end users who want to see a custom appearance. Skinning is a hobby for programmers who have too much time on their hands and not enough user interface design experience